# Check if row contains ANY value *more than once*

Tags: excel, formula

I am doing data analysis and sometimes I need to check and to make sure each row in excel does not have any repeated value. I hope that there is a formula where each time if there's a repeated value in the same row, the value will be highlighted and it doesn't matter what value it is, as long as it's repeated in the same row.

I try to search it everywhere but the closest I can find is below question & answer ( which couldn't apply to me as I need a formula that can highlight any value that's repeated and not only zero):

I have rows which contain grades for students (numerical values), where the number 0 means they missed a class.
I want the row to be highlighted in one color if they have "0" 3 or 4 times, and in another color if they have "0" 5 times or more.

```
=COUNTIF(1:1,0)>=5
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional formatting for this.

The formula you came up with will take the ones with 5 or more times.

For the other, you can use:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(1:1,0)=3,COUNTIF(1:1,0)=4),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the area from A1 to Z1 and downwards, then create the following formula as a Conditional Format:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$Z1,A1)=5
```

Click `Format` to choose a colour. This will colour the cells that contain values that are repeated 5 times. Change A1 to 0 if you are only looking for the number 0 to be repeated; this will paint the whole row.

Click the option `Stop If True` if you only want one colour to apply, then add another rule:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$Z1,A1)>3
```

If necessary, you can change the order of the rules by clicking the up or down arrow.

The following formula will paint the cells containing 0, but only if they are repeated 5 times:

```
=AND(A1=0,COUNTIF($A1:$Z1,0)=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in columns A to Z try this formula in conditional formatting to format any row with any repeated value

`=SUM(IF(COUNTIF($A1:$Z1,$A1:$Z1)>1,1))`

Don't forget to Ctrl+Shift+Enter as this is an array formula.